# Correct way to implement a search function in a symfony project?

Tags: php, symfony

Im learning Symfony and I'm creating a CRUD app for practicing.

I want to implement a search function in the page where I list my db items. I was wondering what is the correct way to achieve this.

Right now, I have created a searchType and searchController with the next code:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class searchController extends Controller
{

    public function searchAction(){

        $formulario = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SearchType');
        return $this->render('searchBar.html.twig', ['form' => $formulario->createView()]);

    }

}
```

```
class SearchType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('key', ChoiceType::class,
                  ['choices' => [
                      'Elegir Campo...' => 0,
                      'Modelo' => 1,
                      'Marca' => 2,
                      'Año' => 3,
                      'Propietario' => 4
                  ]
                  ])
            ->add('term', TextType::class)
            ->add('buscar', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

}
```

I have another controller called itemController, where i have the list, add, modify and delete actions. With the twig render() function, I'm rendering the searchBar in the items list page. Which is the correct way to get the values from the 'key' and the 'term' elements and use them to make queries against the db?

I have tried to achieve this without the searchController/searchType and I used a simple `<form>` in the template and got the key and term values with $request->get() method in the listAction. After I created a switch-case statement to execute queries according to the key value. I could achieve what i wanted like this, but I want to be able to do this the correct way.

Can someone help me/give me some hints on how to continue from this?

Thanks.

Update:

Items Controller:

```
/**
*@Route("/items", name="items")
*/

public function listAction(Request $request){

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $items = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->findAll();
  
  return $this->render('items.html.twig', ['items' => $items]);

}
```

My items.html.twig:

```
{% extends base.html.twig %}
{% block body %}
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:search:search')) }}
 ...
{% endblock %}
```

My searchBar.html.twig:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-inline float-left my-2 my-lg-0'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.key) }}
{{ form_widget(form.term, {'attr': {'class': 'ml-1'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.buscar, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-outline-success ml-1'}}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

What i tried with routing and works with the searchController:

```
/**
* @Route("/search", name="search")
*/
public function searchAction(Request $request){
  
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $formulario = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SearchType');
  $formulario->handleRequest($request);

  if($formulario->isSubmitted() && $formulario->isValid()){

    $data = $formulario->getData();
    $key = $data["key"];
    $term = $data["term"];
    $items = $em->getRepository('Item::class')->findByTerm($key, $term);
    
    return $this->render('items.html.twig', ['items' => $items]);
  
  }
  
  return $this->render('searchBar.html.twig', ['form' => $formulario->createView()]);

}
```

If i go to /search and search for an item, it redirects me to my items page with the item i searched. But, If i use the search bar in my items page that i rendered using `{{ render(controller('AppBundle:search:search')) }}`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are not very far from reaching your goal.

On your Controller, you can update your code to process the incoming request:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request){

    $formulario = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SearchType');
    $formulario->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formulario->isSubmitted() && $formulario->isValid()) {
         $data = $formulario->getData();

         // ... perform some action, such as saving the data to the database or search         
     }

    return $this->render('searchBar.html.twig', ['form' => $formulario->createView()]);
}
```

You can find here more information about [Processing Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms)

To search into your database, you can process your repositories corresponding to the data. For more information about that, you can go here on [Symfony Doctrine documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)

To go further, there is a bundle allowing simplified management of search forms: [Lexik Form Filter Bundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle)

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I get the value of the input field with the getData() function? I also tried $data = $formulario->get('element_name'); but i couldn't get it.

Comment: Also the form doesn't seem to submit, how can I check what's wrong with it?

Comment: Are you using the Symphony debugger/profiler ? https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html

Comment: Yes, when I make a search, i get the post confirmation on the bottom tray, but the request doesnt submit because any code I try in the if statement doesnt work. I've also tried putting a route to the searchAction, so if i go /search, and do the same thing, the request does submit and i can retrieve the items and send them to my items page using return $this->render('items.html.twig', ['items' => $items]) But i want to be able to do the same thing but using the search form in my items page.

Comment: Ok, can you please update your question with your template page and your @Route annotation?

Comment: Update: If anyone facing the same issue, i forgot to add the action for the form. In searchType, simply adding $builder->setAction('/search') solved the issue.